# C/C++ library to blend PNG (including Alpha) with raw ARGB buffer

Tags: c++, c, linux, image-processing, png

I have a PNG with an encoded alpha channel that I want to blend with a raw ARGB image in memory that is stored interleaved.  The PNG is of a different resolution to the image buffer and needs to be resized accordingly (preferably with interpolation).

Whilst I appreciate it's not particularly difficult to do this by hand (once the PNG image is loaded into an appropriate structure), I was hoping to find a good open source image processing library to do the work for me.

I've looked at a few including:

- libGD
- libPNG
- openCV
- ImageMagick
- CxImage
- Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP)

But none of seem to handle all the requirements of loading PNGs, resizing the PNG image, alpha blending into the image data and handling the ARGB format (as opposed to RGBA).

Performance is a concern so reducing the passes over the image data would be beneficial, especially being able to hold the ARGB data in place rather than having to copy it to a different data structure to perform the blending.

Does anyone know of any libraries that may be able to help or whether I've missed something in one of the above?

Comment: I wonder why ImageMagick can't do it. It's very powerful and might be able to do it. Look at IMs `convert`.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: I don't think ImageMagick supports ARGB as a native format. See http://studio.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16873&start=0#p62479. That does gives some hints for using the CLI but I'm not quite sure how that maps to the Magick++ interface.

Comment: Why can't you give up the ARGB requirement? It seems to me that you are either generating this image on the fly, in which case you can do it in any byte order you like, or you are loading it from some external source, in which case the overhead of reordering the bytes on the fly to make your image processing library happy will be totally swamped by the I/O overhead of the load operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with SDL by using [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__gfx_blit_func_8c.html) and [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html).

```
// load images using SDL_Image
SDL_Surface *image1, image2;
image1=IMG_Load("front.png");
image2=IMG_Load("back.png");

// blit images onto a surface using SDL_gfx
SDL_gfxBlitRGBA ( image1, rect, screen, rect ); 
SDL_gfxBlitRGBA ( image2, rect, screen, rect );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pair a file-format library (libPNG or ImageMagick) with a image manipulation library. Boost.GIL would be good here. If you can load the ARGB buffer (4 bytes per pixel) into memory, you can create a GIL image with interleaved_view, and reinterpret_casting your buffer pointer to a boost::gil::argb32_ptr_t

Answer (score 0):

With the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) it is very easy thing to do by using [appendImages](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html) function.

Like this :

```
#include <list>
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int /*argc*/,char **/*argv*/)
{
   list<Image> imageList;
   readImages( &imageList, "test_image_anim.gif" );

   Image appended;
   appendImages( &appended, imageList.begin(), imageList.end() );
   appended.write( "appended_image.miff" );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1: the OP is asking for alpha blending of two images, yielding a single result image, not putting two images into a single file.